# Move products from Virtuemart to Woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce, move, virtuemart, product, webshop

My problem is that I want to set up a Woocommerce webshop, but my old webshop is in Virtuemart where I have about 300 products. Do you know any possible way to move the products from Virtuemart to Woocommerce?

Looking forward to hear from you.

Comment: There is a wordpress plugin for that [link](https://wordpress.org/plugins/cart2cart-virtuemart-to-woocommerce-migration/)

Comment: You could try some migration services such as Next-Cart, Cart2Cart. They are not free, but `Next-Cart` may be more customizable and cheaper than `Cart2Cart`.